# Регистрация *.txt файлов, которые открывались

Tags: java, android, файлы

Мне нужно реализовать сервис, который записывает имя текстового файла, который открывался любой программой.

Сдается мне, что надо использовать

```
Intent.ACTION_VIEW
Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT
```

Уже пробовал подключать action для receiver.

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
<action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT" />
```

А вот выдержка из моей службы:

```
File aFile = new File(filePath);
FileWriter fOut = new FileWriter(aFile, true);
if(Intent.ACTION_VIEW.contains(".txt")) fOut.append("DOC " + time1 + " " + date1 + "\n");
```

Служба походу должна реагировать на `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`. Но как потом понять, что именно *.txt был открыт? И я хоть в том направлении копаю?)

Comment: > И я хоть в том направлении копаю? Нет, поскольку сообщение Intent будет отправлено только одному приложению которое его будет обрабатывать, а остальные подписчики его не получат.

Comment: Нельзя узнать эту информацию. Мы можете отлеживать только создание/удаление/модификацию. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileObserver